# How can I chain two Eloquent Builder variables together?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have a variable `$myQuery` that is an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, built from chaining [Local and/or Dynamic Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#local-scopes). It might be set to something like `Comment::lengthBetween(1000, 50000)->popular()` which would find long, popular comments if it is executed.

How can I get Posts that have comments matched by `$myQuery`? It looks like a job for `whereHas`:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) use ($myQuery) {
    // Insert code here
})->get();
```

Inserting `$query->lengthBetween(1000, 50000)->popular();` gets the correct results for that particular combination of scopes, but `$myQuery` is a *variable* that won't always use those scopes.

The `union` function doesn't work here for several (hopefully obvious) reasons. Neither does setting `$query = $myQuery` (because `whereHas` translates to SQL `where exists` and it needs to link the foreign and primary keys, which is done in `$query`).

So how can I chain `$query` and `$myQuery`?

---

Note:

- This code is just an example, based off the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence); my real code is similar but not about posts and comments.
- I don't want to use `DB::raw()` because it's ugly.

Comment: Did you try using eager load?, or maybe i didn't understand your question.

Comment: @Poldo I don't see how eager loading would help. I'm hoping to only to do this with one query and as little code as possible.

Comment: If `$myQuery` has only `where` clauses, you may use `$query->mergeConstraintsFrom($myQuery);`

Answer (score 0):

You can call scope of other model.

Try something like this.

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) use ($myQuery) {
    $query->lengthBetween(1000, 50000)->popular();
})->get();
```

With mergebindings

```
$posts = Post::->join(
    DB::raw('(' . $myQuery->toSql() . ') comments'),
    'comments.post_id'
    '=',
    'post.id'
)->mergeBindings($myQuery->getQuery())->get();
```

Comment: I know this already but it doesn't work overall. Quoting the question: "Inserting `$query->lengthBetween(1000, 50000)->popular();` gets the correct results for that particular combination of scopes, but `$myQuery` is a *variable* that won't always use those scopes."

Comment: @Laurel can post what would be the value of $myQuery

Comment: Well, I don't know what the value will be since I would like to be able to dynamically generate it from user input elsewhere. All I can tell you is that it queries the comment model, the same as `$query`.

Comment: @Laurel maybe you can use mergeBindings